# SQL Set Time to Midnight in function

Tags: sql, datetime

I have This function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [General].[GetWeekEnding] 
(
@Date DATETIME
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
-- Return the result of the function
RETURN (DATEADD(day, -1 - (DATEPART(dw, @Date) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7, @Date) + 7)
END
```

I need to also set the time to 00:00:00.000 as well as finding the week ending of a provided date any thoughts?

Comment: show input data and what you result expect from this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a UDF for adding time components to dates e.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DateTimeAdd] 
( 
      @datepart         date, 
      @timepart         time 
) 
RETURNS datetime2 
AS 
BEGIN 
      RETURN DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @datepart), CAST(@timepart AS datetime2)); 
END
```

Then in your case you can use it like this:

```
SELECT dbo.DateTimeAdd(DATEADD (D, -1 * DatePart (DW, GetDate()) + 7, GetDate()), DATEADD(hh, 0, CAST(DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), -1)  AS TIME)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since SQL Server 2005, the best way to remove time is to cast to the `date` data type:

```
select cast(@Date as date)
```

I would suggest that you have your function return a `date` instead of a `datetime`.

To get to the week ending, you need a lookup table to map days of the week to integers.  You can do this with `datepart`.  However, that is subject to system settings.  Here is a function:

```
Create FUNCTION [GetWeekEnding] (
   @Date DATETIME,
   @WeekEndingDOW varchar(10)
)
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
-- Return the result of the function
    declare @newdate datetime;
    with lookup as (
        select 'Sunday' as dow, 0 as daynum union all
        select 'Monday' as dow, 1 as daynum union all
        select 'Tuesday' as dow, 2 as daynum union all
        select 'Wednesday' as dow, 3 as daynum union all
        select 'Thursday' as dow, 4 as daynum union all
        select 'Friday' as dow, 5 as daynum union all
        select 'Saturday' as dow, 6 as daynum
       )
    select @newdate = @Date - (select daynum from lookup where datename(dw, @date) = dow) + (select daynum from lookup where @WeekEndingDOW = dow);
    select @newdate = (case when @newdate < @date then @newdate + 7 else @newdate end)
    RETURN cast(@newdate as date)
END;
```

Note that this function does use `datetime` internally.  For some reason that I cannot fathom, you can say "@date + 1" to mean "add one day to the date value" when @date is a datetime.  However, this does not work when @date is a date.  (This is also true of the dateadd function.)

Comment: Isn't SELECT DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) a better solution for getting the day of the week?

Comment: The problem with using `datepart` is that it is dependent on system settings, which might change.  You could use it, and it would work.  But, I find it confusing because it could change from system to system.  I prefer my own lookup table for that reason.